# Pip not installed in virtualenv bin folder

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I encountered a few similar issues on the site but none that seems to answer my issue.

I created a virtual env on ubuntu with the command: `python3 -m venv test`

Now when I activate my environnment and run `which python`, I get the python from my virtual env, but `which pip` gives me the global pip.

If I look at the bin/ folder I do have Python but no pip. Howhever, pip is installed in the sites-package directory.

Anyone has a hint ? I created previously another venv and didn't run into the same problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like something went wrong during the pip installation, however you can use `python -m ensurepip` to install pip afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, but that tells me that requirement is already satisfied (for pip and setyptools) linking the site-packages folder of my venv. So I could call pip from the site package folder but it's still not in the bin folder and if I just call pip it will be my global pip.

Comment: It works again after creating a new env from scratch